# Creating shapes in nativescript-angular project

Tags: nativescript, shapes, nativescript-angular

I am implementing cradle tab bar for my nativescript-angular project. I've already found a good example on nativescripting.com:
https://nativescripting.com/posts/cradle-tab-bar-animation-in-nativescript?utm_source=twitter&utm_medium=tweet&utm_campaign=nativescript

Proposed tab bar was implemented with help of three layouts:

- left layout (left from the circle);
- center layout (where the circle is);
- right layout (right from the circle).

In order to achive smooth transition between center layout and adjacent layouts, center layout was implemented as circle with border that covers half-height white grid ([Design of tab bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/py2iw.jpg)).

My goal is to make a space between circle and another part of tab bar transparent so scrolling of page was visible on background of tab bar.

Now I am trying to make custom shape for center layout (figure that is the result of excluding circle from rectangle). I found an article and video for creating simple shapes but it seems it has no support for nativescript-angular project:
https://nativescripting.com/posts/nativescript-shapes-2-methods-for-creating-shape-views

So, how can I create shapes in nativescript-angular project and how to create advanced ones?

Comment: What every is supported in Core framework is supported on all other frameworks. Consider Angular or any framework / library {N} supports is just a wrapper around Core framework. It's like looking at some JS code `document.getElementById(...)` and say Angular doesn't support that but only #id. It's a browser feature, Angular doesn't have to do anything there. Likewise in the blog post they demonstrate how  you use Core APIs to build shape, it applies for Angular too.

Comment: I guess just setting `clip-path` should do the job for you, you may create different shapes and copy the values from https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/.

Comment: @Manoj Can you show an example or share a link for using clip-path in nativescript-angular project?

Comment: It's just a CSS attribute, put it in your CSS or SCSS file and assign the class name to element. You can use the same example in the tutorial you have pointed.